# Understanding Django and Memcached

Tags: django, memcached

Howdy, I hate to ask such a nooberific question but I am trying to understand the whole Django Memcache process better.

1. I am not expecting a huge amount of traffic on my site, should I still use Memcache?
2. I believe I understand that I have to explicitly tell Memcache what I want it to cache, is this correct? Or does it do it site wide?
3. If I make changes to a Model ( Say I edit a blog entry ) will Memcache know to "refresh" itself or do I need to do that manually?

Thanks peeps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, there's not much point.
2. Yes, you need to tell it what to cache. There is a middleware that tells it to cache everything, though.
3. No, it won't know.